# How do I auto increment by a specific value an existing entity in a table. I also want to add a comment

Tags: sql

The structure of the table is as follows.

> User(UserID, FirstName, Surname, Country, DoB)
> Post(PostID, UserID(FK), Title, Contents, DatePosted, Rating)
> Comment(CommentID,UserID(FK), PostID(FK), Text, Date)

I want to increment by 5 the rating of all posts that have at least one comment with words “thank you” in their text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update Post p
set p.Rating = p.Rating + 5
where exists (select c.CommentID
              from Comment c
              where c.PostID=p.PostID
                and c.Text like '%thank you%'
             )
```

Also you may want to change `c.Text like '%thank you%'` statement to [`MATCH AGAINST` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)